# Nginx config not work at /home/user location for laravel

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I'm Using nginx on linux mint. When i set my site document root to /var/www/Laravel/Public its work fine. But when i set document root to /home/user/Laravel/Public its shows 404. Here is my directories permissions:

```
$ ls -la /var/www/Laravel/
total 208
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data troot   4096 May  9 22:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 www-data troot   4096 May 10 22:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot   1635 Mar 25 03:06 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    815 May  9 23:07 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot 114128 May  9 23:13 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data troot   4096 May  9 22:43 config
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    300 May  9 22:32 .env
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    286 Mar 25 03:06 .env.example
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     61 Mar 25 03:06 .gitattributes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     27 Mar 25 03:06 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    503 Mar 25 03:06 gulpfile.js
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data troot   4096 May  1 14:48 .idea
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     98 Mar 25 03:06 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     87 Mar 25 03:06 phpspec.yml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    777 Mar 25 03:06 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data troot   4096 May 10 21:52 public
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot   1724 Mar 25 03:06 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 resources
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    560 Mar 25 03:06 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data troot   4096 May  9 23:19 storage
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 tests
drwxr-xr-x 26 www-data troot   4096 May  9 23:15 vendor
```

And

```
$ ls -la /home/troot/Code/Laravel/
total 208
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data troot   4096 May  9 22:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data troot   4096 Apr 29 22:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot   1635 Mar 25 03:06 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    815 May  9 23:07 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot 114128 May  9 23:13 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data troot   4096 May  9 22:43 config
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    300 May  9 22:32 .env
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    286 Mar 25 03:06 .env.example
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     61 Mar 25 03:06 .gitattributes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     27 Mar 25 03:06 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    503 Mar 25 03:06 gulpfile.js
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data troot   4096 May  1 14:48 .idea
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     98 Mar 25 03:06 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot     87 Mar 25 03:06 phpspec.yml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    777 Mar 25 03:06 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data troot   4096 May 10 21:52 public
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot   1724 Mar 25 03:06 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 resources
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data troot    560 Mar 25 03:06 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data troot   4096 May  9 23:19 storage
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data troot   4096 Mar 25 03:06 tests
drwxr-xr-x 26 www-data troot   4096 May  9 23:15 vendor
```

I can't Find the problem. Please help. Thanks in advance.